# .htaccess redirect from .html to .php doesn't work

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http-redirect

I changed 10 pages in my root directory from `.HTML` to `.PHP` file.
I am trying to make a redirect so that when someone goes to `www.example.com/page_cats.html` it will automatically redirect to `www.example.com/page_cats.php`.
I don't want to use regex or general rules, as most of the pages are still in the 'old' `.HTML` format, and those which need redirect are just 10. I want to make 10 line of code for 10 redirect.

After looking for some answers here on Stackoverflow I wrote the following code that is still not working (I am using Ampps on my MacBook).

```
RewriteEngine On
# Specific redirects 
Redirect /page_cats.html https://www.example.com/page_cats.php
Redirect /dogs_img.html https://www.example.com/dogs_img.php
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: most likely your .htaccess is not enabled in your Apache config

Comment: "most likely your .htaccess is not enabled in your Apache config" If that were true, IIRC it should throw an HTTP 500 error because it detected .htaccess it wasn't allowed to apply. Apache actually did us a solid here -- it's safer than ignoring it, esp if .htaccess is meant to deny access.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? What is the output from `curl -I http://<your server DNS or IP>/dogs_img.html`? Have you tried clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: @amphetamachine "If that were true, IIRC it should throw an HTTP 500 error" - not if ".htaccess is not enabled" (which is the _default_ - `.htaccess` files need to be explicitly "enabled"). It would only throw an error if `.htaccess` was enabled, but mod_rewrite (or mod_alias - unlikely) was not installed. This is the most likely cause since "I am using Ampps on my MacBook".

Comment: _Aside:_ "I changed 10 pages in my root directory from `.HTML` to `.PHP` file." - But rather than changing the URLs, it would generally be preferable to keep the `.html` URLs and internally rewrite the requests to the underlying/new `.php` files instead of implementing redirects. This avoids you having to change your internal links, "hides" the underlying scripting language (ie. URLs are independent of server-side language) and has zero-impact on SEO (which is presumably why you are implementing the redirect in the first place, although you are trying to implement 302s here, not 301s).

Comment: Thank you very much for the support. As @anubhava supposed, the problem was in the AMPPS configuration, as everything works perfectly online! Also, thanks MrWhite and Amphetamachine, for the tips!

Comment: @amphetamachine: Trust it is all clear now. Please delete your misplaced first comment.